Hermite–Fourier expansion for the median
Let $n$ be an odd positive integer. Let $M : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ be the median function: $M(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ is the median of $x_1,\dots,x_n$. What can be said about the Hermite–Fourier expansion of $M$?
Of course, an actual formula will be of interest but I will be happy to see also some numerical data.
The case $n=3$ is already interesting to me.
In particular, what is the contribution (sum of squares) of the coefficients for degree-$k$ terms?
Clarification: Note that $M$ is a function of $n$ variables  so we need to find the inner product of $M$ with $H_{k_1}(x_1)H_{k_2}(x_2)\dotsm H_{k_n}(x_n)$. These functions form an orthonormal basis with respect to the Gaussian measure on $\mathbb R^n$.
Small Addition
A similar question can be asked for $MAX (x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n)$. Here $n$ can be even and even for $n=2$ is of interest. For the case $n=3$ it could be interesting to compare between the Hermite-Fourier expansion of $M(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ and of $MAX (x_1,x_2,x_3)$.

What do you mean the Hermite--Fourier expansion of  a random variable? I did not downvote your post, but this does seem unclear.

I added a clarification...

What happens when you set up the generating function for those "Hermite-Fourier" coefficients?

@GilKalai I still don't get the point of saying the $x_i$'s are i.i.d. Gaussian real numbers. Does the question have anything to do with that?

@GilKalai : How is the inner product defined?

Sorry, the formulation was sloppy. I hope it is fixed now.

@NoamD.Elkies I dont know

@CarloBeenakker, thank you for the answer regarding the Hermite-Fourier expansion of the density function of the mean which seems closely related. (Sorry for the confusing initial formulation.)
As you wrote, for large values of $n$ the mean and the average get close together and this will also be reflected by the $n$-dimensional Hermite-Fourier expansion that I asked about. I would like to understand more delicately the Hermite-Fourier expansion for the $n$-dimensional question and this may be related also to finer understanding of the Hermite-Fourier expansion of the density function.

For n=3 I'd expect that once you know MAX you easily know MIN, and once you know them both then you get M = SUM - (MAX + MIN), so the two questions are equivalent modulo easier integrals.  In general you can ask for the coefficients of the k-th largest variable for each k=1,2,...,n, and again there'll be a symmetry between k and n-1-k, and the sum over all k will be easy.

I presume you want the coefficients
$$a_k=\int_{-\infty}^\infty p(M)\psi_k(M)\,dM,$$
with
$$\psi_k(x)=\frac{1}{\pi^{1/4}\sqrt{ 2^k k!}} e^{-x^2/2} H_k(x)$$
the normalized Hermite function of order $k$ and $p(M)$ the probability density function of the median $M$ of the $n$ Gaussian random variables.
For $n\gg 1$ the median of $n$ i.i.d. normal random variables has a Gaussian distribution $p(M)=(2\pi\sigma^2)^{-1/2}e^{-M^2/2\sigma^2}$, with $\sigma^2=\tfrac{1}{2}\pi/n$, resulting in $a_{2m+1}=0$,
$$a_{2m}=\frac{(-1)^m\sqrt{(2m)!}}{2^{m}\pi^{1/4}m!}\frac{\bigl(1-\tfrac{1}{2}\pi/n\bigr)^m}{\bigl(1+\tfrac{1}{2}\pi/n\bigr)^{m+1/2}}.$$

Thanks ,Carlo, note that M is a function of $n$ variables so we need an expansion with products of different $H_k$'s.

hmm, OK, I misunderstood the question (before your edit); I'll delete the answer.

since Gil commented on this answer (based on an earlier formulation of the question), and apparently it is of some minimal use, I undeleted it.

Thanks a lot as ever, Carlo.

$\newcommand{\si}{\sigma}\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb R}$As I understand the problem, it is to compute
$$e_{k_1,\dots,k_n}:=EM_nH_{k_1}(X_1)\cdots H_{k_n}(X_n),$$
where $n\ge1$ is an odd integer, the $H_k$'s are the (probabilist's) Hermite polynomials, $X_1,\dots,X_n$ are independent standard normal random variables, and $M_n$ is the sample median of $X_1,\dots,X_n$.
For $n=3$, it is possible to obtain explicit expressions for $e_{k_1,\dots,k_n}$, which are rather simple at least for small values of the $k_i$'s. In particular,
$$e_{1,0,0}=1/3. $$
See details on this below.
However, this seems impossible to do already for $n=5$. Indeed, with (say) $(k_1,\dots,k_5)=(0,0,1,1,1)$ we will apparently have to compute
$$\int_{\Bbb R^5}\prod_{i=1}^5(dx_i\,f(x_i))\,x_3^2 x_4 x_5\,1(x_1\vee x_2<x_3<x_4\wedge x_5)=\int_{\Bbb R}dx_3\,x_3^2 f(x_3)^3 F(x_3)^2,$$
where $a\vee b:=\max(a,b)$, $a\wedge b:=\min(a,b)$, and $f$ and $F$ are respectively the p.d.f. and the c.d.f. of the standard normal distribution. Mathematica cannot do anything with the latter integral. (However, Mathematica can find $\int_{\Bbb R}dt\,t f(t)^2 F(t)^2=\frac1{4\pi\sqrt3}$.)
So, apparently, the latter displayed integral cannot be expressed in elementary or special functions.

Details on case $n=3$: Note that $H_k=(-1)^k f^{(k)}/f$ for $\ge0$, where $f$ and $F$ still respectively denote the p.d.f. and the c.d.f. of the standard normal distribution. So, for (integers) $k_1,k_2,k_3\ge0$,
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
    e_{k_1,k_2,k_3}&= EM_3H_{k_1}(X_1) H_{k_2}(X_2) H_{k_3}(X_3) \\ 
    &=(-1)^{k_1+k_2+k_3}\sum_{\si\in S_3}a(k_{\si(1)},k_{\si(2)},k_{\si(3)}),
\end{aligned}
\tag{10}\label{10}
\end{equation*}
where $S_3$ is the set of all permutations of the set $\{1,2,3\}$ and, for $k,l,m\ge0$,
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
    &a(k,l,m):=\int_{\R^3}dx\,dy\,dz\,1(x<y<z)y f^{(k)}(x) f^{(l)}(y) f^{(m)}(z) \\ 
    &=\int_\R dy\, y f^{(l)}(y)\int_{-\infty}^y dx\,f^{(k)}(x)\,
    \int_y^\infty dz\,f^{(m)}(z) \\ 
    &=\int_\R I f^{(l)}f^{(k-1)}\,\bar f^{(m-1)} \\ 
    &\to\int_\R Iff^{(k-1)}\,f^{(m-1)},\ 
    \int_\R  ff^{(k-1)}\,f^{(m-1)},\ 
    \int_\R I ff^{(k-1)}, \int_\R ff^{(k-1)}  \\ 
    &\to\int_\R ff^{(k-1)} f^{(m-1)},\ 
    \int_\R  ff^{(k)}, \int_\R fF,
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
where $I$ is the identity function, so that $I(y):=y$ for real $y$,
\begin{equation*}
    f^{(-1)}:=F,
\quad
\bar f^{(m-1)}:=1(m=0)-f^{(m-1)}, 
\end{equation*}
and $\to$ in this context means "reduces (by possibly repeated integration by parts) to integral(s) of the following form -- for nonnegative integers $k$ and $m$, which may be different in different expressions".
Next,
\begin{equation*}
    \int_\R fF=\int_\R dF(y)\,F(y)=1/2
\end{equation*}
and
\begin{equation*}
    \int_\R ff^{(k)}=(-1)^k\int_\R f^2H_k,
\end{equation*}
which latter can be easily evaluated explicitly using the explicit expression for $H_k$.
It remains to evaluate
\begin{equation*}
    b(k,m):=\int_\R ff^{(k-1)}f^{(m-1)}. 
\end{equation*}
If $k,m\ge1$, then
\begin{equation*}
    b(k,m)=(-1)^{k+m}\int_\R f^3H_{k-1}H_{m-1}, 
\end{equation*}
which again can be easily evaluated explicitly using the explicit expression for Hermite polynomials.
Finally,
\begin{equation*}
    b(0,0)=\int_\R fF^2=\int_\R dF(y)\,F(y)^2=1/3 
\end{equation*}
and
\begin{equation*}
    -b(1,0)=-b(0,1)=\int_\R f^2F
    =\frac1{2\sqrt\pi}\,P(Y_1/\sqrt2<Y) \\ 
    =\frac1{2\sqrt\pi}\,P(\sqrt{\tfrac32}\,Y>0)
    =\frac1{4\sqrt\pi},  
\end{equation*}
where $Y$ and $Y_1$ are independent standard normal random variables; here we used the fact that $2\sqrt\pi\,f^2$ is the p.d.f. of $Y_1/\sqrt2$.
Thus, $e_{k_1,k_2,k_3}$ can be evaluated explicitly for all (integers) $k_1,k_2,k_3\ge0$. $\quad\Box$

$E\max(X_1,X_2,X_3)H_{k_1}(X_1) H_{k_2}(X_2) H_{k_3}(X_3)$ and $E\min(X_1,X_2,X_3)H_{k_1}(X_1) H_{k_2}(X_2) H_{k_3}(X_3)$ can be evaluated similarly.
In particular (cf. \eqref{10}), for (integers) $k_1,k_2,k_3\ge0$,
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
    &E\min(X_1,X_2,X_3)H_{k_1}(X_1) H_{k_2}(X_2) H_{k_3}(X_3) \\ 
    &=(-1)^{k_1+k_2+k_3}\sum_{\si\in S_3}b(k_{\si(1)},k_{\si(2)},k_{\si(3)}),
\end{aligned} 
\end{equation*}
where, for $k,l,m\ge0$,
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
    &b(k,l,m):=\int_{\R^3}dx\,dy\,dz\,1(x<y<z)x f^{(k)}(x) f^{(l)}(y) f^{(m)}(z) .
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}

Many thanks, Iosif! It looks that we need to concentrate on $n=3$; can we get some feeling on how higher contributions look like and what is the total weight-squared for degree k coefficients for n=3?

@GilKalai : You are welcome! I have added details on $n=3$.
